# Sharing Mutable Map across akka actor children

Tags: scala

I have a large Mutable Map object which occupies so much memory which all the children of the parent need to access or modify values to the same Map.

I am considering just passing the mutable map during child creation as constructor parameters to all the children upon which they can access or modify the map accordingly.

I just wanted to confirm that SCALA actually passes the object reference around and so the Mutable Map will not be copied all over again, instead all the children will be modifying the same Map instance?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this by any means, but might it be a good idea to wrap the mutable map in an actor?

Comment: Alternative: You might want to take a look at [akka STM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/quick_start.html) and see if that fits your use-case. It says _"we’ll build a [mutable] doubly-linked list that can be safely used by multiple threads or actors ... there are also transactional collections (e.g. TMap and TSet) that are replacements for collections from `scala.collection.mutable`"_

Comment: How you can find out if object is copied or not: Debug the program by logging the `hashCode()` value of the map in every actor. If the values are the same, it's with 99.9*% the same object. If they differ, the map gets copied.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad idea.  The Akka team does not recommend [shared mutable state](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/jmm.html#Actors_and_shared_mutable_state) of any kind.

The Akka way to solve your problem would be to make your map immutable and pass it to your children in immutable messages.  If you are convinced that the map has to be mutable then have one actor manage the map and have the other actors send messages to it to retrive / update values.  There is nothing wrong with mutable state within one actor.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a large Mutable Map object which occupies so much memory which
>   all the children of the parent need to access or modify values to the
>   same Map

This is exactly what Akka shines at compared to other concurrency mechanisms. Encapsulating mutable state inside an Actor and sending messages to the Actor to mutate the state is the correct and recommended approach.

So you need to pass an `ActorRef` to any actor who needs to modify the map. The cool thing is that other actor can be on a different JVM and it would still work.

This also takes care of your concern the large memory footprint of your Map.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I ended up using the approach of just passing the object to any actor which requests it using messages.

Comment: passing the Mutable Map object in the message to your Akka actor ?

Comment: I mean we figured out that we don't even need a map. We just passed the object which is a sequence and no longer a map  to all the child actors upon request by which all actors share only one copy.

Comment: I hope that object that you are sharing in the Akka message is `immutable`